# how to determine c3p0 max_statements

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I'm wondering how to properly determine what value to use for c3p0 max_statements. I've experienced some caching dead locks which seems to point back to my max_statements configuration based on all the SO Q&A I've read.

I'm using mysql and the deadlock appears to happen when I'm doing some multi threading where I have 4 active threads.

My configuration

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1800</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3600</property>
```

The exception

```
[WARN] async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@72df1587 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
    Managed Threads: 3
    Active Threads: 3
    Active Tasks:
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@e877a61
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wd9a1o1iea71i8u346|1a799bb]-HelperThread-#2
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@109b1150
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wd9a1o1iea71i8u346|1a799bb]-HelperThread-#0
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@3eb42946
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wd9a1o1iea71i8u346|1a799bb]-HelperThread-#1
    Pending Tasks:
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@52729f95
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wd9a1o1iea71i8u346|1a799bb]-HelperThread-#0,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.realClose(PreparedStatement.java:2765)
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:541)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:938)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wd9a1o1iea71i8u346|1a799bb]-HelperThread-#1,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.realClose(PreparedStatement.java:2765)
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:541)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:938)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wd9a1o1iea71i8u346|1a799bb]-HelperThread-#2,5,main]
        com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.realClose(PreparedStatement.java:2765)
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:541)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:938)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
```

So my question is how do I determine what these values should be. I'm sure there must be away to do this without guessing.

Articles I've read

[should i activate c3p0 statement pooling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920740/should-i-activate-c3p0-statement-pooling)

[How to trace and prevent the deadlock appeared in c3po which is running in seperate processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230863/how-to-trace-and-prevent-the-deadlock-appeared-in-c3po-which-is-running-in-seper)

Answer (score 5):

To resolve deadlocks associated with Statement caching under Oracle / jTDS / mySQL, please make sure you are using a recent c3p0 (0.9.5.1 is the current version), and please see [statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads) and [Configuring Statement Pooling](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_statement_pooling).

TL;DR set config param

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads">1</property>
```

The exact value of `max_statements` is only incidentally associated with this issue. If `max_statements` is too small, you will churn through statements unnecessarily, and this issue, associated with the fragility of `PreparedStatement.close()`, in some drivers will appear more frequently.

However, your value for `hibernate.c3p0.max_statements` is too small for a pool of `maxPoolSize` 50. Even after you fix the deadlock issue, churning through statements will diminish or kill any performance benefit from the statement cache. To compute a good value for `hibernate.c3p0.max_statements` (which maps to `c3p0.maxStatements`), count the number of distinct PreparedStatements that are used *frequently* in your application and multiply that by `maxPoolSize` (or in your case `hibernate.c3p0.max_size`). Or, alternatively, just set `hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection` to the number of distinct PreparedStatements used frequently by your application.

Please see [maxStatements](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxStatements), [maxStatementsPerConnection](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxStatementsPerConnection), and [Configuring Statement Pooling](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_statement_pooling).