# C3P0 Apparent Deadlock

Tags: mysql, database-connection, connection-pooling, c3p0

My server used to see `APPARENT DEADLOCK` in the logs. I have several servers running behind a load balancer, and the interesting thing is I see the DEADLOCK occur on all servers at the same time **(does anyone know why it affects all servers)?**. During this time period, MySQL queries that normally take 200ms take >60 seconds. Here's what logs looked like then:

```
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@58780f76
 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
        Managed Threads: 3
        Active Threads: 3
        Active Tasks: 
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@25ff87d4 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@10ccf7ef (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@3305ec37 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
        Pending Tasks: 
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@39cc9e5a
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@60d46f90
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@17509fea
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@b28bd63
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@56cbdc12
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@15a091b4
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@61ce325
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@48119520
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@4032fb7c
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@518eefff
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@30ea3b20
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@74960088
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@23a8fc7d
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@5ff0ee0
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@642d0644
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@207bc809
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@44d4936f
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@39a10d1b
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@3532334d
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@4bf79e62
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@2bd83398
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@1a202a2d
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@3eacda7f
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@495f5746
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@23f1f906
```

So I came to Stack Overflow and [found this answer which suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704749/how-to-determine-c3p0-max-statements?lq=1) I set `statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads` to `1`. I did this, and I see `DEADLOCK` less frequently and only on a few servers behind the load balancer instead of all.

The logs look a little different now, but during DEADLOCK period, queries still very long:

```
10 Oct 2018 06:33:32,037 [WARN]  (Timer-0) com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@4f39ad63 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
        Managed Threads: 3
        Active Threads: 3
        Active Tasks: 
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@34dee200 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@3727ee6b (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@4afb8b9 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
        Pending Tasks: 
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@384a3b5b
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@7bc700b0
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@731bfd15
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@a88e9bf
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@63f18b56
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@20f0c518
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@caf7746
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@41a7a27d
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@2ee32a24
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@81df2e5
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@7f7fa1e7
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@337503f
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@34b2f877
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@53dfbede
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@512d5ddb
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@68a25969
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@4bf0754a
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@65770ba4
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@5e0f4154
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@249c22ed
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@6c8e5911
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@3179550f
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@15d8a795
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@50966489
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@4ecee95b
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@35640ca0
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@6550f196
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@6816399
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@3fbcd623
Pool thread stack traces:
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,5,main]
                com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.realClose(PreparedStatement.java:2765)
                com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:541)
                com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:41)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:404)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,5,main]
                com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.realClose(PreparedStatement.java:2765)
                com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:541)
                com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:41)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:404)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,main]
                com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.realClose(PreparedStatement.java:2765)
                com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:541)
                com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:41)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:404)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

Any idea how to fix this? I could try disable statement caching altogether but I'm concerned about the general performance hit. Some other relevant parameters:

```
minPoolSize = 30
maxPoolSize = 30
maxStatements = 100
unreturnedConnectionTimeout = 500
idleConnectionTestPeriod = 60
acquireIncrements = 3
C3p0 version = 0.9.1.2
```

**Edit**: I forgot to mention, during this improvement where I saw less deadlocks, I also increased `maxStatements` which could explain the improvement. However now I just see https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/issues/53 which says `version 0.9.2` introduces this new parameter `statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads`. My version is too old. I get no warnings/errors about this parameter not existing.

Comment: I wound up setting maxStatements = 0 and increasing the RDS MySQL hardware. The CPU was 100% when we saw this issue.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's too late, but have you tried to increase the number of `numHelperThreads`?

Comment: Thats not an answer but a comment.